Xampp Installer not downloading
I’m encountering an issue with downloading Xampp from apachefriends.org. When I click the "Xampp for Windows" button, I’m redirected to a SourceForge page that displays a countdown timer. After the timer expires, I’m taken to a post-download page, but the download does not start.
Can anyone help me resolve this issue?
I think there might be an issue with the website or something. Actually, I formatted my disk and I'm reinstalling everything again and everything else downloads perfectly except this.
Also I have a backup of my xampp, but I want to install new as that drive caused some issues before leading to formatting.

why do you still use xampp where there is confguration overhead, try laragon , it has all the things that you require for your and easy to setup. It must be your Internet service provider issue , because its downloading fine here. i tried 5 times

It might be the problem with your internet service provider. You can change mirror to download by selecting option "Problem Downloading" on SourceForge and then under "Choose a different mirror" select "Auto Select".
This method worked for me.
